# Section 508 and "applets and plugins"

Tags: accessibility, wcag

Before the Section 508 refresh, 508 had the following provision:

> (m) When a web page requires that an applet, plug-in or other application be present on the client system to interpret page content, the page must provide a link to a plug-in or applet that complies with §1194.21 (a) through (l). - [source](https://www.access-board.gov/ict/#d22)

I still see statements like this on websites, for example [this one from the National Cancer Institute](https://www.cancer.gov/policies/accessibility), usually to highlight things like flash, PDF, and Microsoft Office viewers.

1. Is such a statement about "plugins" still required by Section 508 or recommended by WCAG? (If yes, can you cite a specific section because I couldn't find one). I think this might not map to the updated 508.
2. Regardless of 508, are statements like these a good idea to have in 2023? After all, PDF viewers are now ubiquitous and available by default in most Windows, OSX, Linux, and Android installs. Several browsers open them out-of-box. I'd also be weary of recommending specific software to users.

Comment: Maybe it’s of interest that the French adoption of the WCAG, [the RGAA, require also documents that can be downloaded to be accessible (French)](https://accessibilite.numerique.gouv.fr/methode/criteres-et-tests/#13.3). So from a more practical standpoint, marking accessible and inaccessible non-web-contents would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

WCAG does not require such a statement but take a look at the "[Conformance](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#conformance)" section of WCAG, specifically section 5.2.4.  It talks about "[accessibility supported](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#dfn-accessibility-supported)" and "[Web content technology](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#dfn-technologies)" which is essentially an applet, plugin, pdf, etc.

It basically defines what external sources might be needed for accessibility but does not require you to put a statement on your website like Section 508 used to require.

You can get a little hint of such a statement in the "[4th Note](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#h-note-45)" where it says:

> **Note:** When citing Web content technologies that have multiple versions, the version(s) supported should be specified.

It's not **requiring** you to cite other technologies, but if you do, and there are multiple versions of that technology, then cite the version that is accessible.